# How can I prevent a dangerous controller from being included in production profile with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

**tl;dr**
How can I exclude a class from being included in the jar file generated by `bootJar`, depending on a Spring profile?

---

*I'm going to intentionally be vague, but will try to provide as much info as possible.*

I have a C# .NET web api (JSON over HTTP/1.1). This api receives an encrypted payload from a third-party. This third-party has a library that is written for Java, but not C#. Due to time constraints and other factors, we have decided that it would be quicker to stand up a Java API with Spring Boot, and make calls to that API, rather than implementing their library ourselves.

The flow is

1. Send encrypted payload to C# API
2. (C#) Send encrypted payload to Java API
3. (Java) Decrypt encrypted payload
4. (Java) Do data transformation/verification using third-party library
5. (Java) Re-encrypt payload
6. (Java) Return encrypted payload to C# API
7. (C#) Send to a different third-party

We have a suite of automated integration tests that are currently written in C#.

We need to make sure that, given a valid payload, when it's sent to the C# API, the payload gets forwarded to the Java API, gets decrypted properly, gets transformed properly, and gets re-encrypted properly for the other third-party to handle.

In order to facilitate this, I have created a new controller on the Java API that takes in the plaintext payload, encrypts it (just like the third-party would) and returns it to the caller. The caller can then send that encrypted payload do a different controller on the Java API to do the decryption+validation, and send the re-encrypted payload back to the caller.

The Java API trusts these automation-created payloads. The Java API generates a new key pair at runtime, and when it receives the plaintext payload, it signs it with the runtime-generated private key, and trusts messages signed with the runtime-generated public key.

The problem I have now, is that **I don't want this functionality to be available in production.** The contents of these payloads are too sensitive for bad actors to be able to manipulate.

I have solved part of the problem by adding the `@Profile("test")` attribute to the controller. This allows me to configure it at runtime like

```
java -jar sensitive-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=production
```

That way, at runtime, spring prevents the controller from working

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-03-16T23:20:00.781+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/dangerous-endpoint"
}
```

However, I understand that nothing is unhackable. As much as possible, I'd like to ensure that this can't be hit by any bad actors that get access to the box; or put differently, even if the attacker gets access to the box, and starts the application with

```
java -jar sensitive-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
```

The controller still won't be functional.

I am building this jar using the spring-boot gradle plugin.

The only way I could think about doing this is preventing the controller from being included in the jar in the first place.

I tried adding this to my build script

```
bootJar {
    exclude('sensitive/dangerous/**')
}
```

but I see the class file still included in the jar.

Then I wondered if there was some way to have the spring plugin intelligently include or exclude files based on a property, like

```
gradlew clean build bootJar -Dspring.build.profile=production
```

but couldn't find anything.

I also tried to exclude the file in the sourceset

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            if (project.environment == 'prod') {
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the class file still ended up in the jar file (under the `BOOT-INF/classes` folder)

**Note:** This controller needs to be available in all non-production environments, so preventing compilation of this file outright is not an option.

How can I exclude a class from being included in the jar file generated by `bootJar`; or is there a way that I can tell gradle to build the files that would be included in a Spring profile?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different tack.

I would write the dangerous controller so that it looked for something very specific in the JVM environment (e.g. a custom system property or environment variable).

- Have the controller test the variable and throw in exception if it detects that it is being used in production.   Fail loudly, and early!   Possibly put this into a static initializer so that the failure occurs if  the controller is loaded / wired.
- Arrange that the property / variable / whatever is set in a way that cannot be accidentally copied to production by your chosen build / deploy methodology.  (There are various ways to do this ... but you have been intentionally vague about the context which makes it hard to suggest an appropriate one.)

This approach has the advantage that it should be immune from someone interfering with the build script.  But it would be advisable to figure out to exclude the controller via the build script **as well**.  (Belt and braces ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with gradle sourceSets.

#### Add this to your gradle.build:

```
def env = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'development'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            if ( env == 'production' ) {
                println "DANGEROUS source set is being used for project complie (env = $env)!"
            } else {
                println "SAFE source set is being used for project complie (env = $env)."
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### You can pass in a project property with "-P".

To compile with dangerous Java code call:

```
gradle clean build bootJar -Penv=production
```

#### The default build will not include dangerous Java code.

#### Note

If you are using an IDE, it many not respect your declared source set. You will have to use the gradle IDE (eclipse, idea) plugins and add the same logic.

#### CI

Stuff like this can usually be passed in via your CI job when deploying to various environments.
Additionally, you could load your application.properties file into gradle or use a system property to determine the environment.

Comment: This does not work. The class file still gets included in the jar. Note that I want the dangerous code to be available everywhere *except* prod.

Comment: Inverse the logic (env != 'production') .  Print out your “sourceset” if you have to. If you are building with gradle and not your IDE, it is not possible for any file that is in a directory named ”dangerous” to be in the jar, it is not even in the “sourceset”. With the springboot plugin, conditionally excluding from the “sourceset” maybe the only way to do this.  I tested twice and it works perfect.  Try just a “gradle clean build” and then inspect the jar file.  Make sure that you have throughly cleaned your class files to ensure it is not being included from a previous build.